# Notification in Oreo without snoozing button

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I was searching for it for a couple of days and didn't find anything.

In android oreo when notification is swiped there are two buttons showing: settings and snooze. I need only settings to be shown, as in my case snoozing doesn't make sense (I'd like this notification to be always visible). 
Anyone knows how to achieve this? I've seen it in other apps, but I'm helpless.

Comment: This is the default android behavior why do you want to hide snooze? snooze makes sense for all notifications. User should have the right to postpone your notification.

Comment: +1 I would need exactly the same. I want to implement my own snoozing, which will actually snooze the whole task on cloud as well. Actually, I want something similar to Google Inbox snoozing - with custom snoozing dialog. Inability to disable system snooze just confuses the user because there are two snooze buttons. Unfortunately, Google Inbox has two as well. Hence, I suppose  we won't achieve this.

Comment: Just a quick observation, notifications that are linked to foreground service don't have snooze button. However creating a dummy foreground service just to display such notification is definitely an overkill :) (Also some "battery managers" may report such application and "scare" user from using the app.)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this one? I have a similar requirement and I don't want the user to snooze my notification.

Comment: @DK Ansh I didn't